# Oracle: Get length of partial string match

Tags: string, oracle, pattern-matching

Imagine I have a table like

```
Name
----
ABCDEFG
ABChello world
ABCDEfoo
ABbar
ABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
zzz
qABCD
ABCqqqGH
ABCABC
```

I want to do a query and figure out how many characters of each string match the desired string "ABCDEFGHIJ," always starting from the beginning. That is...

```
Name               MatchingLength
----               ----
ABCDEFG            7
ABChello world     3
ABCDEzoo           5
ABbar              2
ABCDEF             6
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP   10
zzz                0
qABCD              0
ABCqqqGH           3
ABCABC             3
```

Is there any way to do this cleanly in Oracle? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Also, I could compromise on an answer which only returns one row with the highest MatchingLength, if that's all that is possible.

Comment: what is the matching length of `ABqqqFGH`?

Comment: 2. It's just initial characters.

Comment: Added some clarifying rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know about "clean", but here are two solutions.

```
-- The hardcoded, bad performance. No transformation of your string though.
with patterns as (
        select substr('ABCDEFGHIJ', 1, rownum) txt
        from dual 
        connect by level <= length('ABCDEFGHIJ')
    )
select d.txt, coalesce(max(length(p.txt)), 0)
from dummy d
    left join patterns p
        on instr(d.txt, p.txt) = 1
group by d.txt
order by 2 desc;

-- The cool one with regex. 
-- Though transforming your input string, 
-- this can also be done with ease making something that transorms it for you
-- like in the previous example, more complicated task than the previous,
-- as oracle sucks with string manipulation. You can however write it in java.
select d.txt, coalesce(LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(d.txt, '^A(B(C(D(E(F(G(H(I(J)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)')), 0)
from dummy d;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ba6/23

**UPDATE**

```
with patterns as (
        select substr('ABCDEFGHIJ', 1, rownum) txt
        from dual 
        connect by level <= length('ABCDEFGHIJ')
    )
select d.txt, coalesce(max(length(p.txt)), 0)
from dummy d
    left join patterns p
        on instr(d.txt, p.txt) = 1
where d.txt LIKE substr('ABCDEFGHIJ', 1, 1) || '%'
group by d.txt
order by 2 desc;
```

Updated fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37400/6

Query plan produced tested on oracle 10g

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS       
 SORT ORDER BY                  
  SORT GROUP BY NOSORT          
   NESTED LOOPS OUTER           
    INDEX RANGE SCAN    I <<<< Uses the index.
    VIEW                            
     COUNT                  
      CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING                  
       FAST DUAL
```

Comment: why not just `count(p.txt)`?

Comment: @be here now It works, but not really what I semantically mean to do. Even if it has better performance OP should use the regex approach IMO.

Comment: The regex approach would require me to write ancillary C++ code to convert the input string into a regex. Also my experience with regex in Oracle 10 has been that it is phenomenally slow.

Comment: I gave this approach a shot on our actual production data and it ended up performing a full table scan, unfortunately (the name column is indexed). I also tried converting `instr(d.txt, p.txt) = 1` to `d.txt like p.txt || '%'` and this also failed to dodge the full table scan.

Comment: Yes, your index will break. try `d.txt like substr('ABCDEFGHIJ', 1, 1) || '%'`. Note that when I talk about 'ABCDEFGHIJ', I mean your inputstring which should be a placeholder.

Comment: @StilesCrisis I think the outer join is no longer necessary either.

Comment: Not bad. You managed to hit the index here. I'm going to award the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will want to have the matching count of only those strings which are starting with 
`ABCDEFGHIJ` and for the strings like `qABCD` the matching count will be `0`

```
 SELECT STR,DECODE(SUBSTR(STR,1,1),'A',LENGTH(STR)-
 NVL(LENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(STR,'ABCDEFGHIJ',' '),' ','')),0),0) MATCHING_LENGTH FROM table
```

Comment: This doesn't work for inputs such as 'ABqCD', the `TRANSLATE` function will remove the 'CD' as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle 11gR2 then you can use [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm) like this:

```
with rcte(txt,t, p, c) as
(
  select d.txt , d.txt t, 'ABCDEFGHIJ' p, 0 c  
  from dummy d
  union all
  select txt ,substr(t, 2), substr(p, 2), case when substr(t, 1, 1) = substr(p, 1, 1) then 1 else 0 end 
  from rcte 
  where length(t) > 0  and length(p) > 0  and substr(t, 1, 1) = substr(p, 1, 1)
  )
select txt, sum(c) from rcte
group by txt;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85ba6/37) (thanks to @Roger)

Comment: You query gives wrong result, see [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d03d2/1) - it should return 0 instead of 4 (as far as I understood the question)

Comment: Sadly I believe we only have Oracle 10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the matching criteria is both symbol and position equality (value of pattern `ABCqqqGH` is 5) you might try this:

```
17:57:03 SYSTEM@sandbox> @sf test

VAL
------------------------------
ABCDEFG
ABChello world
ABCDEzoo
ABbar
ABCDEF
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
zzz
qABCD

8 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
17:57:05 SYSTEM@sandbox> @get match
  1  select t.val, count(l)
  2    from test t
  3    left join (select level l from dual connect by level <= length('ABCDEFGHIJ')) i
  4      on substr(t.val, i.l, 1) = substr('ABCDEFGHIJ', i.l, 1)
  5   group by t.val
  6*  order by 2 desc
17:57:07 SYSTEM@sandbox> /

VAL                              COUNT(L)
------------------------------ ----------
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP                       10
ABCDEFG                                 7
ABCDEF                                  6
ABCDEzoo                                5
ABChello world                          3
ABbar                                   2
zzz                                     0
qABCD                                   0

8 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

Comment: No, I want prefix matching. ABCqqqGH ought to be 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
       v_1 number := 0;
v_pattern VARCHAR(26) := '&n';
v_f number;
v_spaces VARCHAR(30) := ' ';
v_l number;
v_c varchar(20) := ' ';
v_n varchar(20) := ' ';
    BEGIN
 v_f := Ascii(SubStr(v_pattern,1,1));
v_l := Ascii(SubStr(v_pattern,Length(v_pattern)));
v_spaces := LPad(' ',Length(v_pattern),' ');
for i in (select str,TRANSLATE(REPLACE(str,' ',''),v_pattern,v_spaces) c1,length(REPLACE(str,' ',''))-nvl(length(replace(TRANSLATE(REPLACE(str,' ',''),v_pattern,v_spaces),' ','')),0) c2 from table 
where ascii(substr(str,1,1)) IN (SELECT DISTINCT Ascii(SubStr(v_pattern,LEVEL,1)) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=Length(v_pattern))) loop
       for j in 1..i.c2 loop
               v_c :=instr(i.c1,' ',1,j);
               v_n :=instr(i.c1,' ',1,j+1);
               if v_c+1=v_n then
                          v_1 := v_1+1;
               end if;
       end loop;
                  if(v_1+1 = i.c2) then
               dbms_output.put_line('String : '||i.str||' and Matching count : '||i.c2);
       else
               dbms_output.put_line('String : '||i.str||' and Matching count : '||((v_1)-1));
       end if;
   v_1 := 0;
end loop;
FOR k IN (SELECT str FROM table WHERE NOT(Ascii(substr(str,1,1)) IN (SELECT DISTINCT Ascii(SubStr(v_pattern,LEVEL,1)) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=Length(v_pattern)))) LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('String : '||k.str||' and Matching count : '||v_1);
 END LOOP;
 end;
```

Comment: Can this be generalized to work with any search text, not just ABCDEFGHIJ? Obviously that is placeholder text, not what I actually need to search for.

Comment: Yes it will be , but the only thing is it should be starting with CAPS

Comment: What's with the `ascii(substr(str,1,1)) between 65 and 74)`?

Comment: I have updated the code check it !!
It will work for any input of caps

Answer (score -1):

I hope the following helps:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTME ( TNAME VARCHAR2(30));

INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABCDEFG');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABChello world');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABCDEzoo');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABbar');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABCDEF');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('zzz');
INSERT INTO TESTME VALUES('qABCD');  

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_MLENGTH( P_INPUT VARCHAR2)
 RETURN NUMBER 
IS
 -- COMBARING STRING
 C VARCHAR2(10) := ('ABCDEFGHIJ');
 N NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN 
  FOR I IN 1..LENGTH(P_INPUT) LOOP
   IF SUBSTR(P_INPUT,I,1) = SUBSTR(C,I,1) THEN
    N := N + 1;
   ELSE
    RETURN N; 
   END IF;  
  END LOOP;
RETURN N;   
END;
/


SELECT TNAME , GET_MLENGTH(TNAME) FROM TESTME ;

TNAME                          GET_MLENGTH(TNAME)
------------------------------ ------------------
ABCDEFG                                         7
ABChello world                                  3
ABCDEzoo                                        5
ABbar                                           2
ABCDEF                                          6
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP                               10
zzz                                             0
qABCD                                           0
```